# PropertyChanged is ignored when Binding to IEnumerable where reference stays the same

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I created a minimal example to illustrate the binding issue.
`IEnumerable<string> NewReference` gets updated as expected.
`IEnumerable<string> SameReference` is not updated, presumably because the reference is the same. `Raise("SameReference");` was not enough to make WPF update the reference.

Is there something that can be done to make the WPF framework revaluate `SameReference` even though it has the same reference?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Azure">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Update" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SameReference}" Margin="5" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewReference}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<string> data = new List<string> {  };
        public IEnumerable<string> SameReference { get { return data; } } //this returns a reference to an unchanged object
        public IEnumerable<string> NewReference { get { return new List<string>(data); } } //this returns a reference to a new object
        //ObservableCollection<string> conventional is known but not the point of this question

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Raise(string propertyName)
        {
            if(null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.Add("This is data.");
            Raise("SameReference"); //successful notify, ignored values
            Raise("NewReference"); //successful notify, processed values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs wow - this has been 4 years :) and yes it does. I will vote to close this question as well.

Comment: Hey, cheers! That leaves a breadcrumb which makes it easier for future researchers of this issue (like me, today.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is intentional behavior. If you want collections to update implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (or use a class that already does, like [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)).