# PropertyChanged is ignored when Binding to object where reference stays the same

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm pretty new to the WPF/Binding world, but now I'm using it for some time with some degrees of success.

Now I'm stuck with a problem very similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072670/propertychanged-is-ignored-when-binding-to-ienumerable-where-reference-stays-the), but regarding a class instead of an IEnumerable. I'm not sure if the behavior is intentional also for a class or if there is a way to solve it.

Let's say I have my simple custom class "Vector3" that contains 3 doubles
Vector3.cs

```c#
    public class Vector3
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }

        public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public Vector3(Vector3 vec)
        {
            X = vec.X;
            Y = vec.Y;
            Z = vec.Z;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is Vector3))
                return false;

            Vector3 other = obj as Vector3;

            return X == other.X && Y == other.Y && Z == other.Z;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (X.GetHashCode() * 42) ^ Y.GetHashCode() + Z.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have a user-control that exposes a DependencyProperty of this type

ucVector3.xaml.cs

```c#
public partial class ucVector3 : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value",
                     typeof(Vector3), typeof(ucVector3),
                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(_OnModelChanged)));

        private static void _OnModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Binding worked! I've received a new Vector3 " +
                              "with value X = " + (e.NewValue as Vector3).X); 
        }

        public Vector3 Value
        {
            get
            {
                return (Vector3)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            }
        }
    ...
```

Then I try to use this user-control binding the Value property like in this example:

MainWindow.xaml

```xaml
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.Example"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Azure">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Update" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="Button_Click" />
        <local:ucVector3 Value="{Binding SameReference}" Margin="5" />
        <local:ucVector3 Value="{Binding NewReference}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```c#
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (uiContext != SynchronizationContext.Current)
            {
                uiContext.Send(_ =>
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }, null);
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private Vector3 newValue = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        public Vector3 SameReference { get; set; }
        public Vector3 NewReference { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            newValue.X = newValue.X + 2;
            newValue.Y = newValue.Y + 3;
            newValue.Z = newValue.Z + 4;

            SameReference = newValue;
            NewReference = new Vector3(newValue);

            OnPropertyChanged("SameReference"); //successful notify, ignored values
            OnPropertyChanged("NewReference"); //successful notify, processed values
        }
    }
```

Pressing the button the first time both user-controls will be updated with (3,4,5), but from the second time, only the "NewReference" property will be updated in the right user-control.

I get that for IEnumerables WPF will propagate the OnPropertyChanged event only if the reference is different, and changes in the IEnumerable need to call the INotifyCollectionChanged event instead.

Why my "OnPropertyChanged("SameReference")" is not propagated? I changed the values, I want the event to propagate to update the interface, or I wouldn't call the event...

Is this behavior intentional? Why it checks the object reference and not maybe if it is Equals? Is there a way to "force" the event to go through? Or how should I organize my classes in this case?

[Here you can download the example solution described in this question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A5ggr-DJM0DEy2GiwdzT6MaaAcSoEAXt), created in VisualStudio2015.

Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("SameReference")` is ignored because the value of the SameReference property did not actually change. It's still the `newValue` object. In order to make this work, Vector3 would also have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event for its X, Y and Z properties.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, yes I get that this is the reason, but I don't get why it should work like that, I need to... "Vector3" is a library class it shouldn't know anything about the "graphics". 
And this is the reason for the Model/ViewModel, but if this is the default behaviour I should wrap every single object in a view model it is terrible

If only it would check for object.Equal instead of only watching for the reference of the object, or at least make an option to force the event even when the object is the same...

Comment: Calling `SameReference = new Vector3(SameReference)` doesn't look too complicated...

Comment: No it's not complicated, and it's the solution I'm using right now, but it seems more like a hack than a solution. Recreating a new object every time a value changed is not what I would call a clean code :) I was hoping there was another, more "correct" way to force WPF to propagate the event...

Answer (score 0):

from i have seen in your project, you have to comment these lines in your ucVector3.xaml.cs, these lines avoid to update your usercontrol:

```
        if (value.X == lastNudValue.X && value.Y == lastNudValue.Y && value.Z == lastNudValue.Z)
           return;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
No that is not the problem, the value that arrives in the usercontrol via the PropertyChanged event is different (like you can see in the MainWindows.xaml.cs at every button press, I add 2,3,4 to the x,y,z of the Vector3), in fact when I call OnPropertyChanged("NewReference") the event arrives at the usercontrol and is indeed updated, with OnPropertChanged("SameReference") instead the event is not raised by the WPF system and do not arrive at the usercontrol....